# How to rewrite a subquery with a join

Tags: sql

Heyho,
I need to rewrite the following code without useing a subquery:

```
SELECT country, region, name
FROM wcities
WHERE( country, region ) NOT IN ( SELECT country, code FROM regions )
AND country = 'IT'
AND region is NOT NULL;
```

I tried it with:

```
select c.country, c.region, c.name
from wcities c
join regions r on c.country <> r.country AND c.region <> r.code
where c.country = 'IT' 
AND c.region is NOT NULL;
```

I can see why that does not work, but I can't see what I need to do it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I also recommend `NOT EXISTS` over `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a `left join` this would be:

```
SELECT c.country, c.region, c.name
FROM wcities c LEFT JOIN
     regions r
     ON r.country = c.country and r.region = c.region
WHERE r.country IS NULL AND
      c.country = 'IT' AND
      c.region is NOT NULL;
```

That said, I would recommend `NOT EXISTS` for this purpose:

```
SELECT c.country, c.region, c.name
FROM wcities c         
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM regions r
                  WHERE r.country = c.country and r.region = c.region
                 ) AND
      c.country = 'IT' AND
      c.region is NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Do you mind providing the `NOT EXISTS` example?